# How do you join one table to two other tables each with a composite primary key?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have two tables in a MySQL database that I want to combine into one table in another database. The tables are formed of four columns which together form a composite primary key. Below is an example of one of the tables:

```
class GamesATP(Base):
    __tablename__ = "games_atp"
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "oncourt",
                      "extend_existing": True}

    ID_T_G = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("oncourt.tours_atp.ID_T"), primary_key=True)
    ID_R_G = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("oncourt.rounds.ID_R"), primary_key=True)
    ID1_G = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("oncourt.players_atp.ID_P"), primary_key=True)
    ID2_G = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("oncourt.players_atp.ID_P"), primary_key=True)
```

The second table is identical save for `atp`=`wta` and `ATP`=`WTA`.

My idea was to append the data from the two tables into a new table with a new column `tour_id` that would be `0` for `atp` and `1` for `wta`. I'll also add a new `match_id` column to be the primary key.

To then build an append query I figured I'd need to define the relationships between the two tables as 2x `ForeignKeyConstraint`s as follows:

```
class MatchesBLG(Base):
    __tablename__ = "matches_blg"
    __table_args__ = (
        ForeignKeyConstraint(
            ["tour_id", "tournament_id", "round_id", "p1_id", "p2_id"],
            [
                "0",
                "oncourt.games_atp.ID_T_G",
                "oncourt.games_atp.ID_R_G",
                "oncourt.games_atp.ID1_G",
                "oncourt.games_atp.ID2_G",
            ]
        ),
        ForeignKeyConstraint(
            ["tour_id", "tournament_id", "round_id", "p1_id", "p2_id"],
            [
                "1",
                "oncourt.games_wta.ID_T_G",
                "oncourt.games_wta.ID_R_G",
                "oncourt.games_wta.ID1_G",
                "oncourt.games_wta.ID2_G",
            ]
        ),
        {"schema": "belgarath", "extend_existing": True},
    )

    match_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    tour_id = Column(Integer, index=True)
    tournament_id = Column(Integer, index=True)
    round_id = Column(Integer, index=True)
    p1_id = Column(Integer, index=True)
    p2_id = Column(Integer, index=True)
```

This gives me the error:

```
ArgumentError: ForeignKeyConstraint on belgarath.matches_blg(tour_id, tournament_id, round_id, p1_id, p2_id) refers to multiple remote tables: 0 and oncourt.games_atp
```

I have a sneaking suspicion I'm not supposed to have two constraints within the same table but I'm hopelessly out of my depth here. What is the best way to create the joins?

Comment: `"0"` is interpreted as a table, hence the error. Why do you need the (overlapping) foreign key constraints in place? You will run into trouble even after fixing the `tour_id` issue, if either `games_atp` or `games_wta` does not contain the same key value as the other, because the foreign key constraints say: "this key must be found in that other table".

Comment: I was trying to create links between the tables. Should I create just normal relationships instead? Or even define relationships at the point of querying?